# How do I mint a Fungible SPL token with name, symbol, and other Metadata?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token

I am fairly new to Solana development and currently learning how to mint fungible tokens with custom metadata. I am able to mint a SPL-Token on devnet using spl-token library, however finding it bit confusing for minting a token with metadata. which library is preferred for creating metadata, is it @metaplex/foundation.js or @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata? I also found some people are using @metaboss. Wanted to know which is the preferred approach to mint new token with metadata. I would like to add this Token on Radium with openmarket ID, does it need a specific way in which metadata will be added.

Thanks Sam

Answer (score 0):

Both Metaplex libraries are fine, But Using `@metaplex/foundation.js` is convinient. You can also create The NFT from spl-token cli it self with the new SPL Token 2022 token extensions. But They are not well integrated as of now.